# Sort files in a directory by their text character length and copy to other directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to find the smallest file by character length inside of a directory and, once it is found, I want to rename it and copy it to another directory.

For example, I have two files in one directory `~/Files` and these are `cars.txt` and `rabbits.txt`

Text in cars.txt:

`I like red cars that are big.`

Text in rabbits.txt:

`I like rabbits.`

So far I know how to get the character length of a single file with the command `wc -m 'filename'` but I don't know how to do it in all the files and sort them in order. I know `rabbits.txt` is smaller in character length, but how do I compare both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort the files by size, then select the name of the first one:

```
 file=$(wc -m ~/Files/* 2>/dev/null | sort -n | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')
 echo $file
```

Comment: Okay, this definitely works giving the name of the file as an output and this can then be used as a variable. Thanks a lot, I think I'll manage with the rest. I'll keep the post updated and bring a complete answer if I reach it.